# PrimeFaces calendar/hibernate - send date only to database

Tags: spring, hibernate, calendar, primefaces, spring-webflow

I have a form which inserts a date into a table. When primefaces calendar is used, the date is correct, but the time is added as well (in my case: 00:00:00.0)

here's my form:

```
<h:form>
        <h:messages/>
        <h:inputText value="#{testBean.saveTabletest.first}"/><br/>
        <p:inputMask value="#{testBean.saveTabletest.second}" mask="99999"/><br/>
        <p:calendar id="testcal" value="#{testBean.saveTabletest.dates}" dateOnly="true" showOn="button"/><br/>
        <p:commandButton value="Send" action="save"/>
</h:form>
```

And here is how the date is inserted in the database :  2012-10-03 00:00:00.0

I want the date inserted into the database without the time. The column in the table is a "date-column"

Is there a primefaces property that I can set to do this? or do I have to change the function that saves the data in the table (i am using hibernates saveOrupdate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the pattern attribute of p:calendar and declare the corresponding testBean member as Date.

Comment: Thanks, setting the pattern attribute did it.